# Does nesting collections in MongoDB provide any additional features? Or less?

Tags: mongodb

If I have have the collection db.posts and db.posts.activity, does that provide me with any additional features to use amongst the two collections as opposed to have db.posts and db.post-activity? ... Or is it the feature just having it namespaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no additional features. The usage of the . is just for visual namespacing. In the end there are two collections.